# Como apagar uma DIV caso exista uma palavra em outra DIV em jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if, condição

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte condição:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($("#content .productName").html().indexOf("JBL","Oversound")==-1) {
 $("#pague-so").hide();}
});
```

No caso, quero que a div #pague-so seja ocultada caso a div .productName contenha a palavra JBL ou Oversound no texto.
Como podem perceber, não obtive êxito na condição acima.
Alguém poderia dar alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa para ficar mais configurável é utilizar expressões regulares.

No exemplo o [REGEX.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) irá retornar `true` caso contenha a palavra `Oversound` ou `JBL` e então você fará o tratamento que precisar.

```js
var texto = $('#product .productName').html();
var regex = /Oversound|JBL/;

if (regex.test(texto)) {
  $('#product #conteudo').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
  <div class='productName'>Woofer 12" Oversound OVS-X 5K2</div>
  <div id="conteudo">Conteúdo ou wathever</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pedro, não consegui aplicar essa condição. A página em questão é essa: 
http://www.premiershop.com.br/caixa-de-som-portatil-jbl-go-wireless-1173700/p

Comment: Tente detalahar o máximo quando tiver um problema Jean, isso ajuda a comunidade a te ajudar. No teu site o `productName` é uma classe e não um `id`. Tente isso `$('.productName')`

Comment: Pedro peço desculpas pelo inconveniente, todavia o código que deixei na pergunta, o productName já estava informado como classe.
De qualquer maneira, agradeço imensamente pelo apoio prestado!
Testei o código e ele funcionou com a seguinte condição:
    $("document").ready(function() {
    var texto = $('#content .productName').html();
    var regex = /Oversound|JBL/;
    if (regex.test(texto)) {
      $('#pague-so').hide();
    }});

Comment: Ótimo. :) Agora lembre de marcar as repostas dos colegas como úteis e aceitar uma também caso tenham respondido sua pergunta.

Comment: Ainda não tenho reputação :/ mas quando tiver, farei com o maior prazer. Obrigado mais uma vez Pedro.

Answer (score 1):

você não vai conseguir realizar consultas múltiplas utilizando o indexOf, porém você pode usar uma expressão regular.

```js
var testes = {};
testes.teste1 = "Nada a encontrar";
testes.teste2 = "JBL Motors";
testes.teste3 = "Oversound Waves";
testes.teste4 = "JBL Oversound";

var regex = /(JBL|Oversound)/gi;
for (var teste in testes) {
  console.log(testes[teste], testes[teste].match(regex));
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var regex = /(JBL|Oversound)/gi;
if(!$("#content .productName").html().match(regex)) {
 $("#pague-so").hide();}
});
```

Comment: TobyMosque e DIego F, não consegui inserir essa condição na página que necessito. A página seria essa: http://www.premiershop.com.br/caixa-de-som-portatil-jbl-go-wireless-1173700/p

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `:contains()`, que verifica se no elemento contém o valor passado como parâmetro. Veja abaixo como usar.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button').click(function () {
   if ($('.example:contains("Teste")').length > 0){
      $('.hide').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="example">
    Teste
</div>
<div class="hide">
    Esconder
</div>
<button id="button">
Clique
</button>
```